# No known predicate type could be determined from Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel Error while creating a Goal item

Tags: xdb

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.1 and I also confirmed that all analytics are working. However, after creating new Goal item and rendering some live pages to gather analytics data, it shows this error. I enabled xProfile for Anonymous users through xConnect and can see the user's visited pages, but it doesn't update in Experience Analytics .

The part of error says

> No known predicate type could be determined from
>   Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel.Conditions.Channel.CurrentInteractionIsOnChannelCondition,Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel

**Error Detail:**
https://gist.github.com/udt1106/251ed8cc6f0de96a82dcd0cc9f23cca4

Is there anyone having the same issue?

Thank you in advance.

**======== Actual the error was after creating new Goal Item ========**

Comment: did you make any changes on sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Tagging/Tagging/__Semantics field?

Comment: Experience Analytics are update once a day. Did you wait enough time for new data to become visible?

Comment: @VladIobagiu I didn't change any thing on that field and the source value is the default `StartSearchLocation={154D56CC-0DE2-43C7-BBC0-A25BD7FFD901}&Filter=_path:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901|-_group:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901`

@grg The update of Experience Analytics is based on how you set session time. Mine is every an hour, the data updates and still can't see the data even it shows in Experience Profile.

Answer (score 4):

Have you migrated from Sitecore 8.x to 9?

This error is being caused due to a redesign of rule set in Sitecore 9. I had the same issue and got the following response from Sitecore support:

> This error looks related to the fact that the rule set has been
>   redesigned in Sitecore 9.0, therefore if you have upgraded to the
>   latest version of Sitecore from any 8.x version, you must update all
>   of your custom filters. You do this by setting and configuring new
>   rules in the new rule set. Every rule that was available by default in
>   Sitecore 8.x has a new matching rule in the Rule Set Editor in
>   Sitecore 9.0. If you do not update your custom filter to use new
>   rules, the Reporting database cannot aggregate any visits from
>   contacts and your reports will not show any data. For more details
>   please see the following topic:
>   https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/configuring/update_a_custom_filter_to_use_new_rules
>
> Please note that because filters and rules are dependent on a segment,
>   after you update your custom filter to use new rules, you must also
>   redeploy all segments that use the filter with the new rule.

Based on the error dump you attached, the issue is being caused by the following filters that were in Sitecore 8.2, but not in 9:

[image]

These filters are referencing the following segments:

[image]

You have two options:

1) Follow the instructions above for all the filters and update the rules to use the new Sitecore 9 rules and then re-deploy the segments.

2) If you are not using those filters, you can delete the filters as well as the dimension and re-deploy marketing definitions. You may have to clear all tables in your ReferenceData database and then a re-deploy the marketing definitions (a simple deploy of marketing definitions did not remove the deleted dimension/segments for me).

Answer (score 1):

I came across the following exception as well during a Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.1 upgrade:

`No known predicate type could be determined from Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel.Conditions.Channel.CurrentInteractionIsOnChannelCondition,Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel`

Symtoms were Visitors appearing in Experience Profile, but nothing showing on the dashboard charts.

The solution that worked for me was point 2 in @rameez answer.

`2) If you are not using those filters, you can delete the filters as well as the dimension and re-deploy marketing definitions. You may have to clear all tables in your ReferenceData database and then a re-deploy the marketing definitions (a simple deploy of marketing definitions did not remove the deleted dimension/segments for me).`

The following steps did the trick (note I'm hosting in Azure PaaS):

1. Clear down ALL tables in the refdata-db SQL Database.
2. Deploy Marketing Definitions
3. Restart my CD, CM, Rep & PRC App Services